# How do I get the onClick function to work?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, cart

When I click on the shopping cart, it's supposed to activate the display of the cart like it does in `<html>` but when it's redone in `reactjs`, it doesn't call the function.

Can someone please show me how to get the cart to display?
  https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-feistel-pz8j9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You can't simply paste a whole html page into the return of a component and expect it to work. Specially when you have 2 onClick events to functions that don't even exist in the the whole file. If you want to learn React I recommend starting at their [docs](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Comment: Like @NicolasHevia suggested, you need to learn and understand the basics of React. The react docs is a very good starting point.

Comment: Placing ***all*** the logic and handlers into index.js ***AND*** directly manipulating the DOM are very much react anti-patterns. Other than using React to load static html into the `root` div you're not using react at all.